# how to redirect to homepage in django-microsoft-auth if there is no next parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I registered the app in Azure AD and configured my Django app so I can log in using a Microsoft account. The problem I am facing is changing the redirect from the admin page to my homepage.

Mu redirect URI on Azure looks like this:

```
https://localhost:8000/microsoft/auth-callback/
```

What do I need to do to change the redirect to  `https://localhost:8000/home`

Comment: Why cant you just put return redirect('home') in your callback function if successful?

Comment: when I change return then it opens a new window and redirects me in this window to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of researching I cloned the repository and found in the `login.js` file this piece of code:

```
// redirect to next URL if it was provided
let new_path = this.parseGETParam('next') || '/admin';
window.location = origin + new_path;
```

The only thing to do is to change `/admin` to `/home` or whatever path you want to put. No need to change anything in the callback function.

I hope it will help someone.